# RDS 2012 R2 - Where are a Users Windows Credentials stored?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rds

We have 4 RDS Servers which our users can be logged on to, balanced by a broker. On login and log-out a users profile is copied to a from a separate file server.

I'm trying to find out where a user windows credentials would be stored on a Users roaming profile.
On a normal desktop they would be stored in Control Panel --> Credential Manager --> Windows Credentials.

However I cannot find out where they would be stored in their profile so that it is transferred between each server when they login in and out.

Any help is apricated.

Answer (score 0):

They are stored here:

`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Vault` but honestly I don't know if you can simply copy them across computers.

Comment: Hi Swisstone. I was looking at editing them. However in our RDS environment users don't have access to the Credential Manager through Control Panel. I did however find this article which did help. https://windowsreport.com/add-remove-edit-windows-credential-manager-files/#:~:text=You%20can%20also%20open%20the,in%20the%20snapshot%20directly%20below.